# the eigenspace corresponding to the non-zero eigenvalues of $\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}\Sigma_{\mathrm{b}}\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Notation**:
Define $A:= \Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}\Sigma_{\mathrm{b}}\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, which has rank $K-1$. $[k]:=\{1,\ldots, k\}$
$$
\Sigma_{\mathrm{b}} := \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k (\nu_k - \nu)(\nu_k - \nu)^\top
$$
where $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_K \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\nu := \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k\nu_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$,$\sum_{i=1}^K\pi_i=1,\pi_i\geq0$.

**Background**:
Here's a part of my look at the proof of the paper：

> For any $v \in \mathbb{R}^p \setminus \{0\}$,
> $$ v^\top\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}\Sigma_{\mathrm{b}}\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}v= \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k v^\top \Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}(\nu_k-\nu)(\nu_k-\nu)^\top \Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}v \neq 0 
> $$
> if and only if $v^\top\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}(\nu_k-\nu)\neq 0$ for some $k \in [K]$. Thus, the eigenspace corresponding to the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$ is
> spanned by $\bigl(\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}(\nu_k-\nu):k\in[K]\bigr)$.

**Question**: I don't know how to use the previous sentence to get to the conclusion of the subsequent one.

Comment: if $v$ is an eigenvector, then $\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}\Sigma_{\mathrm{b}}\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}v=\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}(\nu_k-\nu)(\nu_k-\nu)^\top \Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}v=\lambda v$. Let $\alpha_k=(\nu_k-\nu)^\top \Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}v$. So $v = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k\Sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^{-1/2}(\nu_k-\nu)\alpha_k$, $\alpha_k \neq 0$ for some $k \in [K]$.